# How to add a row in gridview of Devexpress

Tags: devexpress

I have a form where i have some text boxes and a Gridview(with Columns in it).the values entered in textboxes should be added as a row in gridview when pressing a ADD button..below is the code in the click event of ADD button..It add as a single column not as a row..Please help me with this.

```
        BindingList<string> Grid_data = new BindingList<string>();            
        Grid_data.Add(txtMaterial.Text.ToString());
        Grid_data.Add(txtPlastic.Text.ToString());
        Grid_data.Add(txtCoatingtype.Text.ToString());
        Grid_data.Add(txtManufacturer.Text.ToString());
        Grid_data.Add(txtManuDate.Text.ToString());
        Grid_data.Add(txtLineSize.Text.ToString());
        Grid_data.Add(txtFootage.Text.ToString());
        DGMaterial.DataSource = Grid_data;
        GV_Material.PopulateColumns();
```

Comment: You should think about using a class. So your BindingList is from Type myClass. Then every value is one row and every Property of your Class is a column like Fares told you in answer.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with, when you write : `Grid_data.Add(someString)` it adds a new element to the binding list not to the row. You have to understand that each element of the `BindingList` represents a row, not a value for a cell.

What you should do is the following :

```
BindingList<List<string>> gridData = new BindingList<List<string>>(); 
gridData.add(new List<string>() {"someString", "anotherString"}); // Your inputs here
DGMaterial.DataSource = gridData ;
GV_Material.PopulateColumns();
```

Hope that helps !